# how create VIEW for local work, without update in TABLE?

Tags: php, mysql

How to create a VIEW that it does not update data in a TABLE? For example, I want to delete rows only in the VIEW and the TABLE, on which the established VIEW, that there should be no deletions ... how to do it?
like this does not work ...

```
"CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW $prefix"
. "Test_View AS SELECT * FROM Table1 WITH LOCAL CHECK OPTION";
```

it is rather to check ... please, help!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a `VIEW` where you can't update/delete data, add a distinct (e.g. on a unique key, where it essentially doesn't have an effect).

See the [MySQL Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/view-updatability.html) on updatable views:

> There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable. To be more specific, a view is not updatable if it contains any of the following:
>
> Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
>
> DISTINCT
>
> GROUP BY
>
> ...

Comment: Note: for views based on multiple tables, the operation of adding data (INSERT) only works if it is added to the only real table. Deleting Data (DELETE) for such views are not supported.

Comment: @ezepovartur: there are a couple of more operations which make a VIEW  nonupdatable..

Comment: As far as I remember your first response was that delete rows from a VIEW in general can not be!? Therefore your advice on VIEW will not inspire confidence ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting Rows from a view will delete them from the corresponding table.

You really should alter your view definition to exclude the rows you do not want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to be using a view for this. You would need a second table that is updated by a on insert / on update trigger, if you want the table to exist permanently. Otherwise just create a temporary table for each query by using [INSERT..SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) statements.